# MapRoute behaving differently depending on URI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, routes, .net-4.5

I have an MVC pattern where, for backwards compatibility of a website migration, I need to support two specific .php files. One (mywebsite.com/aFolder/select.php) behaves perfectly: the controller is called with the right action. The other does not (mywebsite.com/index.php). In the latter case the browser simply redirects (or gets redirected) to mywebsite.com (default Home controller, Index method).

My RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "php2",
        url: "aFolder/select.php",
        defaults: new { controller = "Testtt", action = "Foo" }
        );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "php1",
        url: "index.php",
        defaults: new { controller = "Testtt", action = "Foo" }
        );

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

My Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="PhpHandler1" path="index.php" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    <add name="PhpHandler2" path="aFolder/select.php" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

FWIW the controller too:

```
public class TestttController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

(Setting a breakpoint inside Foo gets hit on /aFolder/select.php but not on /index.php)

It's something about the index.php being in the root rather than a subfolder that makes it behave differently. Any ideas why?

Comment: I have had limited success with URL rewriting but still get frustrating exceptions. A rewrite to go to /MyController/MyAction would be great, as long as the original URL and its parameters are still available.

Answer (score 0):

After going around in circles for months (on and off) and the last couple of days intensively, I eventually found another way - still URL rewriting but not by using web.config rules. Ignore my OP - this is far simpler for the two .php page requests I need to handle. Provided here such that it might be useful to someone.

Handlers in web.config:

```
<add name="PhpHandler1" path="index.php" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
<add name="PhpHandler2" path="Foo/select.php" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fullOriginalpath = Request.Url.ToString();
    if (fullOriginalpath.Contains("index.php"))
    {
        Context.RewritePath("/Redirect/Index");
    }
    [...+select.php, etc...]
}
```

Simplified for brevity, no error/exception handling shown. Then a standard controller called RedirectHandler with an Index returning ActionResult (or whatever).